# How to use arma::vec as key in std::map

Tags: c++, dictionary, armadillo

I've implemented the following code to update a Markov model but the compiler doesn't allow me to use an armadillo vector as key in a std::map. Any ideas?

```
typedef std::vector<std::map<arma::vec, int>> vmaps_t;
struct markov
{
    uint8_t maxord;
    vmaps_t m_maps;
    std::vector<char> m_chars;

    markov(uint8_t maxord)
    {
        m_maps = vmaps_t(maxord);
    }
    void update(const arma::vec &v)
    {
        for (size_t ord = 0; ord < maxord; ord++)
        {
            if (v.n_elem > ord)
            {
                if (std::find(m_chars.begin(), m_chars.end(), v.back()) == m_chars.end()) //just to tell elem not in vect...
                {
                    m_chars.push_back(v.back());
                }
                arma::vec seq = v.rows(v.n_rows - ord, v.n_rows - 1);
                if (m_maps[ord].find(seq) == m_maps[ord].end())
                {
                    m_maps[ord][seq] = 0;
                }
                m_maps[ord][seq]++;
            }
        }
    }
};
```

error: cannot convert ‘arma::enable_if2, arma::Col, arma::glue_rel_lt> >::result {aka const arma::mtGlue, arma::Col, arma::glue_rel_lt>’ to ‘bool’ in return
       { return __x < __y; }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To use *anything* as a key in a `std::map` you need that "anything" to implement a `operator<`. That operator needs to implement a *strict weak ordering* for elements.

If the class you are working with does not currently implement such an operator it cannot be a map key. The solution is to add/implement such an operator.

Comment: @Moleson [std::unordered_map](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map) is something entirely different. It uses a hash function to organise elements into buckets. The two are not comparable - they have different requirements. Please read the documentation for the container you are using.